# How to declare packages with Quasiquotes

Tags: scala, abstract-syntax-tree, scala-macros, scala-quasiquotes

I am trying to use quasi quote to generate the package AST.  I have a string variable that lists out the package path such that

`val pkg = "database.dao"`

When I use quasi quote **`q"package $pkg`**, it tells me that I need a `RefTree` instead.  I tried searching for a while now and still haven't found an answer to convert the string to `RefTree`

How do I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on pg 7 of this [slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/cb372/scala-cache)

It turns out I will need to generate my own AST using multiple `Select()`s if I want to dynamically inject the package variable.

```
  def selectIdentity(directory: String): Select = {
    val dirs = directory.split('.').reverse
    val lastIndex = dirs.length - 1

    def apply(i: Int = 0) : Select = if (i < lastIndex - 1) {
      Select(apply(i + 1), TermName(dirs(i)))
    } else {
      Select(Ident(TermName(dirs(lastIndex))), TermName(dirs(lastIndex - 1)))
    }

    apply()
  }
```